# Compacting a dataset in Apache Jena Fuseki

Tags: dataset, jena, large-data, fuseki

Hello fellow RDF enthusiasts.

I have deployed Jena Fuseki server as an endpoint to collect some great amount of event data coming from a cloud service infrastructure, later to use the dataset as an ultimate source of knowledge for service monitoring frontend. But the dataset grows larger very fast.

I've learned that there's a way to compact a TDB2 dataset. How do I do that from the Fuseki environment?

Comment: Currently, the server has to be shutdown, then run the `tdb.tdbcompact` then restart the server.

Comment: Ah, that's something I've been afraid of. :-/ Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there's no way of doing the compaction online from the Fuseki environment. What I've discovered though was that neither the `tdb.tdbcompact` command compacts the database enough as the difference in my case was somewhere about 2-4 % of the database size.

What I do instead is to dump the whole dataset, clear the database and load the dataset back again. The result is unbelievable: From 50 GiB database down to 1 GiB.

I scheduled this to be done daily together with backups.

Answer (score 2):

As of Jena 3.17.0 released 2020-11-25 there is a `/$/compact/{name}` endpoint in the [Fuseki HTTP Administration Protocol](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-server-protocol.html#compact), with more details [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb2/tdb2_admin.html#compaction).

- Noted there: read requests continue during compaction but writes are held up until it finishes.
- The old data directories, eg. Data-0001, remain but could be removed to save storage space after compaction completes.
- As a reference for size and timing, a 55G database created solely through POSTs to fuseki compacted to 6.8G in ~20m on a MacBook Pro 2019 (SSD).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a TDB2 backend.

As per [the docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb2/tdb2_admin.html#compaction), you can run `tdb2.tdbcompact`. The code it runs is [here](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-db/jena-tdb2/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/tdb2/sys/DatabaseOps.java#L207), which shows that it blocks writers (not readers) and creates a new `Data-000X` (incrementing `X`) directory which then switches over to being the live DB once the compaction is complete.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But not directly from the Fuseki environment.